# How to request and store many objects from a json API that serves only one object once?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, axios

I want to build a home page that shows movies trends. As the **API only serve one movie (one object) once**, my logic is to send many request and store them into an array.

```
const [trends, setTrends] = useState([]);
const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});
const trendsTitles = ["dune", "annette", "cendrillon", "mon frere", "athena", "footloose"];

async function getData(title) {
await axios
  .get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[apikey]&t=" + title)
  .then((response) => {
    setMovie(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });}

useEffect(() => {
trendsTitles.map((title) => {
  getData(title);
  trends.push(movie);
  setTrends(trends);

});}, [])
```

When i run the code, the React Dev Tools shows `trends` as an array of empty objects, With more object than the `trendsTitle.length`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you want to call the request multiple times in order to get more than one trend movie ? but what's the role of `trendsTitle` ?

Comment: @monim `trendsTitle` is and array that contain trends title. It is with those title that request are send.

Answer (score 0):

`setTrends` and `setMovie` are asynchronous.

The code in the effect is synchronous, so `trends.push(movie)` will only do `trends.push({})`.

Also you should never mutate data with React `useState` hook (reference is the same so React wont re-render your component).

Prefer something like this:

```js
const [trends, setTrends] = useState([]);
const trendsTitles = [
  "dune",
  "annette",
  "cendrillon",
  "mon frere",
  "athena",
  "footloose",
];

async function getData(title) {
  axios
    .get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=[apikey]&t=" + title)
    .then(res => {
       setTrends(prevTrends => [...prevTrends, res.data])
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
  trendsTitles.map((title) => {
    getData(title);
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot something. I also want to use the `getData` function when we enter a movie title in an text input. So it should only request one movie and store it in `movie`.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this one plz.

```
setTrends([...trends],[...res.data])
```